# Recursive updateDynamic? (Scala for the Impatient, Chapter 11, Exercise 11)

Tags: scala

I'm currently self teaching myself Scala using the (excellent) [Scala For the Impatient (2nd Edition)](http://www.horstmann.com/scala/) from Cay Horstmann. The task for *Chapter 11, Exercise 11* is to write a class using *extends Dynamic* that allows getting and setting system properties, with usage like:

```
val props = new DynamicProps(System.getProperties)
val javaHome = props.java.home
props.set.some.property = "somevalue"
```

I got as far as being able to use *selectDynamic* to fetch properties (although I think the solution is clunky and needs improvement):

```
import scala.language.dynamics

class DynamicProps(val props: java.util.Properties) extends Dynamic {
  def selectDynamic(name:String): DPropHelper = {
    new DPropHelper(name, props)
  }
}

class DPropHelper(val name: String, val props: java.util.Properties) extends Dynamic {
  def selectDynamic(name:String): DPropHelper = {
    new DPropHelper(this.name + "." + name, props)
  }
  override def toString: String = props.getProperty(name)
}
```

but I am at a complete loss with respect to how to use the corresponding *updateDynamic*, having tried this:
    import scala.language.dynamics

```
class DynamicProps(val props: java.util.Properties) extends Dynamic {
  def updateDynamic(name: String)(value: String): DPropHelper = {
    new DPropHelper(name, props)
  }

  def update(key: String, property: String) = {
    println(s"DynamicProps update(${key}, ${property}) called")
  }

  def selectDynamic(name:String): DPropHelper = {
    new DPropHelper(name, props)
  }
}

class DPropHelper(val name: String, val props: java.util.Properties) extends Dynamic {
  def updateDynamic(name: String)(value: String): DPropHelper = {
    new DPropHelper(this.name + "." + name, props)
  }

  def selectDynamic(name:String): DPropHelper = {
    new DPropHelper(this.name + "." + name, props)
  }

  def update(key: String, property: String) = {
    println(s"DPropHelper update(${key}, ${property}) called")
  }

  override def toString: String = props.getProperty(name)
}
```

I'm pretty sure that I do not need the helper class, and could get the same effect by either building the "stack" of path values in a local list and returning *this*, or simply be building new *DynamicProps* recursively.

My question is though, how on earth do I manage to use *updateDynamic* to eventually trigger an update operation - my tests of the above show that neither *update()* methods fire.

**Edit - possible solution**

In the best of [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://rubberduckdebugging.com), having posed the question a possible solution occurred to me. This now works as anticipated, although I would welcome advice on stylistic improvements as this still feels very clunky:

```
import scala.language.dynamics

class DynamicProps(val props: java.util.Properties) extends Dynamic {
  def updateDynamic(name: String)(value: String): DPropHelper = {
    new DPropHelper(name, props)
  }

  def selectDynamic(name:String): DPropHelper = {
    new DPropHelper(name, props)
  }
}

class DPropHelper(val name: String, val props: java.util.Properties) extends Dynamic {

  def updateDynamic(name: String)(value: String): Unit = {
    props.setProperty(this.name + "." + name, value)
  }

  def selectDynamic(name:String): DPropHelper = {
    new DPropHelper(this.name + "." + name, props)
  }

  override def toString: String = props.getProperty(name)
}
```

and the test

```
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers}
class DynamicPropsTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  "property" should "be retrievable" in {
    val instance = new DynamicProps(System.getProperties)
    val result = instance.java.home
    result.toString should be (System.getProperties.getProperty("java.home"))
  }

  "property" should "be settable" in {
    val instance = new DynamicProps(System.getProperties)
    instance.fred.mary.jane = "alice"
    System.getProperties.getProperty("fred.mary.jane") should be ("alice")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution!